# Array Input, Output

Tags: assembly, assemblies, nasm

My program will get numbers as input from user using an array and will print the numbers on the monitor. SO expecting Input and Output of my program is as following:

```
    i/p: 1 2 3 4 
    o/p: 1 2 3 4
```

But my program gives the output in this fashion excluding  number:

```
    o/p: 4 3 2
```

My program is as following:

```
   section .data
       msg db "%d"
       four dd 4
       msga db "%d",10,0
   section .bss
       arr resd 4
   section .text
       global main
      extern printf,scanf
   main:
      xor ecx,ecx
   lp:
      mov ebx,arr
      mov eax,ecx
      mul dword[four]
      add ebx,eax
      pusha

      push ebx
      push msg
      call scanf
      add esp,8
      popa
      inc ecx
      cmp ecx,4
      jnz lp

      mov ecx,3
 lp1:
      mov ebx,arr
      mov eax,ecx

      mul dword[four]
      add ebx,eax
      pusha
          push dword[ebx]
      push msga
      call printf
      add esp,8
      popa
          dec ecx
      jg lp1
```

Will you pls advice me in this program? I am using ubuntu 11.04
THanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop, `ecx` changes from 0 below 4:

```
 xor ecx,ecx ;;; ecx <= 0
lp:
 ...
 inc ecx ;;; ecx <= ecx + 1
 cmp ecx, 4
 jnz lp ;;;  if (ecx!=4) goto lp;
```

In the second loop, `ecx` changes from 3 downto 0, but *not including* 0:

```
 xor ecx, ecx ;;; ecx <= 0, useless here
 mov ecx, 3   ;;; ecx <= 3, overwrites 0
lp1:
 ...
 loop lp1     ;;; ecx <= ecx-1; if (ecx>0) goto lp1;
```

You can reorganize the second loop to make it exactly like the first one if you want to print the same array at the same order. Just replace stuff from the second loop which I *quoted* here with the respective parts of the *first* loop.

Comment: Anton Kovalenko: Dear Sir, I tried to fix the code as you suggest.(pls see the re edited code above). But the output still shows 4 3 2.

Comment: What's so hard about **copying** code from part 1 to part 2, **verbatim**, without any **creative thinking**? You initialize ECX with 3, then you decrement ecx, and `dec ecx; jg..` is roughly equivalent to your former `loop`. Instead you should start with `xor ecx, ecx`, then `inc ecx`, then `cmp ecx,4` and `jne lp1` -- **exactly** as you already do in the first loop.

Comment: Please don't reedit the code in a way that makes the question and answers senseless for future readers. If you have a new problem, post a new question. If everything works, just leave *problematic* code as is, so it remains clear what was the problem and how it was solved. That's why I've rolled back your last edit.